# Disable nginx, but keep it installed

Tags: centos, nginx, daemon

I have nginx installed on CentOS and now I need it to be disabled (including on reboot), but keep it installed for further use.

Should I only remove `/etc/init.d/nginx` file? Or is there more graceful way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop
>
> sudo chkconfig nginx off

then confirm with

> chkconfig --list | grep nginx

Comment: no need to pipe to grep, `chkconfig --list <daemon>` will show you just that one line

Comment: good point. i pipe like it's a nervous tick.

Comment: You know you've got a problem when you `cat | less`